# Filtering rows based on specific values: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
ID Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
1   0        0       50      100     0
2   0        0       0        0      0 
3   0        0       0        50     0
4   0        100     0        0      0 
5   50        0      100      50     50
```

I would like to filter `IDs` which has only one non-zero values. For example `ID == 1` has two non-zero values but `ID == 3 and 4` has only one non-zero values and I would like to filter them.

The expected output is ID 3 and 4.

```
ID Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
3   0        0       0        50     0
4   0        100     0        0      0
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions if `ID` is column with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and count not `0` values by compare and `sum`:

```
df[df.drop('ID', 1).ne(0).sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

Or if need omit first column:

```
df[df.iloc[:, 1:].ne(0).sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

If `ID` is index:

```
df[df.ne(0).sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

Comment: ah the `.drop` syntax is much cleaner than setting the index.

Answer (score 1):

use a boolean filter with `.set_index`

you can filter the index by using `.loc`

```
df.set_index('ID').loc[df.set_index('ID').gt(0).sum(axis=1).eq(1)]


    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
ID
3        0       0       0      50       0
4        0     100       0       0       0
```

---

```
print(df.set_index('ID').gt(0).sum(axis=1).eq(1))

ID
1    False
2    False
3     True # <-- filter this row
4     True # <-- and this.
5    False
dtype: bool
```

---

another way using `.filter`

```
df.loc[df.filter(like='Val').gt(0).sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.set_index('ID')[(df1.set_index('ID')>0).sum(1)==1]
```